# how to replace a single choice with a select my cart

Tags: javascript

For now I have a cart in javascript that works
But when I click the add to cart button

there is only one product added

I would like to replace this with a select so that the user can choose the number of articles to add

I tried to modify the code but when I select a quantity and I click on add to cart

It's always two that adds up

```
 var MonPanier = (function() {
      panier = [];

      function Item(nom, prix, quantite) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.quantite = quantite;
      }

      function savepanier() {
        console.log("saving",panier)
       // sessionStorage.setItem('MonPanier', JSON.stringify(panier));
      }

      function loadpanier() {
       // panier = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('MonPanier'));
       panier = []
      }
    //  if (sessionStorage.getItem("MonPanier") != null) {
    //    loadpanier();
    //  }

      //variable objet 
      var obj = {};

      obj.ajouter_produit_dans_panier = function(nom, prix, quantite) {
        for (var item in panier) {
          if (panier[item].nom === nom) {
            //panier[item].quantite ++ ; ancien code 
            panier[item].quantite;
            savepanier();
            return;
          }
        }
        var item = new Item(nom, prix, quantite);
        panier.push(item);
        savepanier();
      }

      obj.setquantiteForItem = function(nom, quantite) {
        for (var i in panier) {
          if (panier[i].nom === nom) {
            panier[i].quantite = quantite;
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      obj.enlever_produit_de_panier = function(nom) {
        for (var item in panier) {
          if (panier[item].nom === nom) {
            panier[item].quantite--;
            if (panier[item].quantite === 0) {
              panier.splice(item, 1);
            }
            break;
          }
        }
        savepanier();
      }

      obj.enlever_produit_de_panier_tous = function(nom) {
        for (var item in panier) {
          if (panier[item].nom === nom) {
            panier.splice(item, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        savepanier();
      }

      obj.clearpanier = function() {
        panier = [];
        savepanier();
      }

      obj.totalquantite = function() {
        var totalquantite = 0;
        for (var item in panier) {
          totalquantite += panier[item].quantite;
        }
        return totalquantite;
      }

      obj.totalpanier = function() {
        var totalpanier = 0;
        for (var item in panier) {
          totalpanier += panier[item].prix * panier[item].quantite;
        }
        return Number(totalpanier.toFixed(2));
      }

      obj.listpanier = function() {
        var panierCopy = [];
        for (i in panier) {
          item = panier[i];
          itemCopy = {};
          for (p in item) {
            itemCopy[p] = item[p];
          }
          itemCopy.total = Number(item.prix * item.quantite).toFixed(2);
          panierCopy.push(itemCopy)
        }
        return panierCopy;
      }

      return obj;
    })();

    $('.ajouter-panier').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var nom_option = "";
      var prix_option = 0;
      var nom = $(this).data('nom');
      var prix = Number($(this).data('prix')) + prix_option;
      var quantite = $(this).data('select');
      MonPanier.ajouter_produit_dans_panier(nom, prix, quantite);
      //MonPanier.ajouter_produit_dans_panier(nom, prix,1); ancien code 
      afficherpanier();
    });
$('.clear-panier').click(function() {
  MonPanier.clearpanier();
  afficherpanier();
});

$('.choix_livraison').click(function() {
    
const cases = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choix_livraison"]');
    for (const x of cases) {
    if (x.checked) {
        afficherpanier();
    }}
});

function afficherpanier() {
  var panierArray = MonPanier.listpanier();
  var output = "";
    var countart=0;
    var countart2=0;
  var count=0;
     for(var i in panierArray) {
             output += "<div class='row' style='border-style: ridge;  border-width: 1px; border-color: #8ebf42; background-color: #d9d9d9;margin-bottom:5px;'>"
        + "<div class='col' style='text-align: center;border-left: solid;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;'><button class='btn btn-danger effacer-item' data-nom='" + panierArray[i].nom + "'>X</button></div>"     
      + "<div class='col' style='text-align: center;border-left: solid;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;'>" + panierArray[i].nom + "</div>" 
      + "<div class='col' style='text-align: center;border-left: solid;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;'>" + panierArray[i].prix.toFixed(0) + "  euro</div>"
      + "<div class='form-inline col' style='text-align: center;border-left: solid;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;'><div class='input-group'><button class='btn btn-primary moins-item' data-nom='" + panierArray[i].nom + "'>-</button>"
      + "<input type='number' min='1' class='form-control item-quantite' style='width:55px !important' data-nom='" + panierArray[i].nom + "' value='" + panierArray[i].quantite + "'>"
      + "<button class='btn btn-primary plus-item' data-nom='" + panierArray[i].nom + "'>+</button></div></div>"
            //+ ' = ' 
      + "<div class='col' style='text-align: center;border-left: solid;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 5px;'>" + panierArray[i].total + " euros</div>" 
       +  "</div>";
       count++;
       countart += panierArray[i].quantite;  // somme des unités d'articles
       countart2 = countart
}

  $('.show-panier').html(output);

  if (Livraison == 3)
  {
     // % du prix total total correspondant au prix de la livraison
const cases = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choix_livraison"]');
//const cases = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="ajout");
for (const x of cases) {
if (x.checked) {
let nom_choix_livraison = x.dataset.nom;
let prix_choix_livraison = x.value;
//console.log(panierArray[i] );

let prix_et_livraison = (( (MonPanier.totalpanier()*Poucentage_Livraison))) + Number(prix_choix_livraison) + Number(Forfait_Livraison ) ;
document.getElementById('amount').value = prix_et_livraison ;
$('.total-panier').html(prix_et_livraison.toFixed(2));
document.getElementById('livraison-detail').innerHTML ="<div class='col' style='text-align:right;background-color: #78b8df;visibility:hidden;'> (" + nom_choix_livraison + ")" + prix_choix_livraison + " euro(s)</div>";
document.getElementById('remise').innerHTML =MonPanier.totalpanier()*Poucentage_Livraison_opposse ;
document.getElementById('nouveau_prix').innerHTML =(MonPanier.totalpanier()- (MonPanier.totalpanier()*Poucentage_Livraison_opposse));
document.getElementById('frais-fixe').innerHTML =Forfait_Livraison ;
document.getElementById("prix_depart").innerHTML  = MonPanier.totalpanier(); 
document.getElementById("countart_bas").innerHTML = countart;
document.getElementById("countart_haut").innerHTML = countart;
break;
  }
  }
  }

  $('.total-panier-modal').html(MonPanier.totalpanier());
  $('.total-quantite').html(MonPanier.totalquantite());
  if ((Qte_Minimum == 1) && (Number.isInteger(MonPanier.totalquantite() / Qte_Minimum_Valeur) == false) && (MonPanier.totalquantite() != 0))
  {
document.getElementById('qte_minimum_report').innerHTML = txt_qte_minimum_bad;
  }
  else if ((Qte_Minimum == 1) && (Number.isInteger(MonPanier.totalquantite() / Qte_Minimum_Valeur) == true) && (MonPanier.totalquantite() != 0))
  {
document.getElementById('qte_minimum_report').innerHTML = txt_qte_minimum_ok;
  }
  else if (Qte_Minimum == 1)
  {
    document.getElementById('qte_minimum_report').innerHTML = txt_qte_minimum_defaut;  
  }
  else if (Qte_Minimum == 0)
  {
document.getElementById('qte_minimum_report').innerHTML = "";
  }  
}

$('.show-panier').on("click", ".effacer-item", function(event) {
  var nom = $(this).data('nom')
  MonPanier.enlever_produit_de_panier_tous(nom);
  afficherpanier();
})

$('.show-panier').on("click", ".moins-item", function(event) {
  var nom = $(this).data('nom')
  MonPanier.enlever_produit_de_panier(nom);
  afficherpanier();
})

$('.show-panier').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
  var nom = $(this).data('nom')
  MonPanier.ajouter_produit_dans_panier(nom);
  afficherpanier();
})

$('.show-panier').on("change", ".item-quantite", function(event) {
   var nom = $(this).data('nom');
   var quantite = Number($(this).val());
  MonPanier.setquantiteForItem(nom, quantite);
  afficherpanier();
});

afficherpanier();
```

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Produit 02 (15.00 €)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="02">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-end">
        <a style="cursor:pointer;" data-nom="Produit 02" data-prix="15.00" data-select="02" class="btn btn-primary ajouter-panier">Add to Cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to comment out the sessionStorage since it does not work in a stacksnippet - we are missing `afficherpanier`

Comment: Change where you have this.data.select to this.value and have a select with value 1,2,3

Comment: Thanks for the answers

I modified the select

on the other hand, I can't send you affichepanier

there is too much code

how can I do
thank you

Comment: here I managed to add affichepanier

Comment: Now things are better, but if a user chooses

for example choose 2 for item 1

choose 2 for item 2

choose 2 for item 3

then change your mind

and choose 1 for item 2

look at the result

the total is equal to 4